# htaccess rewrite for internal links based on current URL or referrer

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I am a real beginner at htaccess, apache and regex, so if i am asking stupid question please forgive me.

**Here is my case:**

I have a forum, that allows access optionaly for users on

```
http://mysite.net or 
https://mysite.net.
```

The idea is that it is a hobby project on a cheap shared hosting with a self-signed certificate, so i really need https only for moderators - ordinary users, guests, search engines should use HTTP.

The forum software seems a bit ignorant of relative links and always creates absolute link for internal pages. So if a user using HTTP version of the forum posts internal link to another topic, it will be

```
http://mysite.net/topic....
```

And if a user using HTTPS version posts internal link it will be 
    httpS://.....

**The problem:**

If a user from the HTTP version clicks HTTPS link, he gets redirected to the https site, which is undesirable because of the warning for selfsigned certificate from browser scares users. If a moderator form the HTTPS version clicks HTTP link it is even worse, because he gets unlogged (i do use secure session cookies and the session breaks in that scenario!).

**The soluton:**

I was thinking about htaccess rewrite rules, something like "IF referrer contains

```
https://mysite...
```

AND requested url has

```
http://mysite.net/something
```

rewrite it to be

```
https://mysite.net/something".
```

And vise versa.

But i don't really understand apache mod_rewrite and regex an don't know how to do it. Searched a lot of tutorials and a couple of questions on Stackoverflow but couldn't adapt the examples. The only results i'm getting are nothing/unconditional redirects/infinite loops.

Here are a couple of tried rules that just don't work for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://mysite\.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^http://mysite\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.net/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Note: i just tried to visit whatismyreferer.com from link inside post and it says "no referrer". So the http_referer won't work. But how to do the job then?

Comment: Interestin folks are "moderators" here. "Closed as offtopic" despite the fact that i already read at least 3 dozens of questions here about mod_rewrite an htaccess and ssl. By offtopic somebody probably meand "too general"... well sorry, i'm a beginner, i can't ask boolean type questions "is this or this the right syntax". Thanks to Jon Lin for answering the question despite being closed! To know that my request is impossible is still a useful info, at least i will not try anymore with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a mod_rewrite solution for this because by the time the rewrite rules get run, the request has already been made and whatever ill side-effect has already taken place. By the time you've checked whether it was a user clicking on the https link, the bad cert warning has already happened because the cert is sent *before the request is even made*. By the time a moderator clicks on a non-https link, the request has already been made and the cookie isn't sent, the moderator is logged out. Although, it's possible that the secure cookie isn't overwritten by the HTTP request and when the moderator switches back to HTTPS, the old session cookie is preserved.

The fix really **needs** to be made to your forum software. The **https://mysite.net** part simply needs to be removed and everything will work.

Comment: Thank you very much. Another possible workaround is to use un-secure cookies and then everything is OK, or to purchase a validated certificate and force everything on SSL with the above rewrites, but i don't want to resort to this for now. Actually i also tried patching the PHP of "magic urls" of PHPBB 3.0.11, but it seems another bug happens on post edit (links are re-parsed in a wrong way and).